# MATLAB: Plot variance of elements in each bin of histogram?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, variance

Data: Array of real valued numbers. (say XArray)

To plot: A histogram superimposed with the plot of variance(/IQR) of elements in each bin.

Problem: I need the variance for each bin of the 'elements in each bin'. (elements are numeric.) It can only be done if there is way to access the elements put in each bin and not just 'how many element are in each bin (count)'

I am using MATLAB

Thanks

Comment: did you already had a look at the various outputs [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) provide? For example indices, you could use to index `XArray` to find the elements of each bin.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to sort your data and divide it up based on bin width. You will then have access to the data in each bin to perform a variance calculation.